# Unhappy Problem with Price Rules magento 1.8 and 1.9

Tags: magento-1.8, price, price-rules

[image]

When I cancel and create a new price rules with the same parameters, it happens sometimes after 24h a problem once the problem occurs only after three days. The problem I have at the other two sites just as it comes magento ver. 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the cron in magento for the price rules to reflect every day, its how the system works. Else if you enable the catalog price rules but it will last only for a day and the next day it will disappear.

You can search google for how to enable cron jobs in magento. Good starting point here http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job. This task is mostly an operations task depending on the hosting provider you are using you can set up the cron job easily. I hope this answers your query

Comment: Thank you very much Vivek Gounder. I did Setup Magento Cron Jobs in cPanel. In a few days I will see the result.